# PHP MongoDb driver: How to set timeout for executing a code

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the following code which executes a piece of code on the MongoDb's side:

```
$mongoCode = new MongoCode('/* Some JS code */');
$db->execute($mongoCode, array(
    'socketTimeoutMS' => 1000000,
));
```

As you see I have tried to set timeout for the code's execution by setting the `socketTimeoutMS` value in second parameter of `execute()` function. But it does not work. Documentations in PHP website indicate that the second parameter of execute() command is sent to code as arguments.
How can I set timeout for `MongoDB::execute()`? Please note that I am using version 1.5 of MongoDB driver for php and MongoCursor::$timeout is deprecated and does not work anymore.

Answer (score 7):

You can set the `socketTimeoutMS` on MongoClient:

```
$mongo = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017", 
    array(
        "socketTimeoutMS" => 100000
    )
);
```

The `args` parameters for the `execute` method are passed to the code not to the driver.

You can also set a timeout just when executing the command:

```
$result = $mongo->dbname->command(
    ['eval' => $code],
    ['socketTimeoutMS' => 1]
);
```

Alternatively, if you're not executing commands, you can set the timeout on the cursor:

```
$cursor = $collection->find([]);
$cursor->timeout(10000);
```

This will obviously not work on the `execute` command, because that command doesn't return a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You want the [MongoDB::command](http://www.php.net//manual/en/mongodb.command.php) implementation for this which actually accepts the argument:

```
<?php
$mongo = new MongoClient('mongodb://192.168.2.3/test');
$db = $mongo->test;

$code = new MongoCode( 'sleep(100); return "hello";' );
try {
  $res = $db->command(
    array("eval" => $code),
    array( 'socketTimeoutMS' => 1 )
  );


  echo var_dump( $res );

} catch (Exception $e) {

  echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";

}

?>
```

Note that even though the exception will be thrown for the timeout, this does not not actually stop the code running on the server. That you would have to handle yourself.

Look into the [`killOp()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.killOp/) and [`currentOP()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/) methods, with their usage and implementation for a way to control and processes left running after your timeout expires on this operation.

Really try to look for other approaches rather than executing JavaScript on the server like this.